# -Filter not working when input file has more than once line

Tags: loops, powershell

I have this script and it's working 100% , but only for a single item

I want to loop the script and get content from a txt file
You see, my scipt search for a specific file and copy it to an existing folder with the same name of the file. 
So what I want is to get the folder's name and the file's name from 2 txt files and loop the script

I have manage to get the content from the txt files but I can't loop the script if I add a second line with new values in my txt files.
I always get the error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is
>   not supporte d.

Ok this is my script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
# Setup source and destination paths
$Src = '\\192.168.0.216\home\'
$Dst = 'C:\TEST\120629B\'

# Wildcard for filter
$Extension = '120629B.jpg'

# Get file objects recursively
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Filter $Extension -Recurse |
    # Skip directories, because XXXReadMe.txt is a valid directory name
    Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} |
        # For each file
        ForEach-Object {

            # If file exist in destination folder, rename it with directory tag
            if(Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $Dst -ChildPath $_.Name))
            {
                # Get full path to the file without drive letter and replace `\` with '-'
                # [regex]::Escape is needed because -replace uses regex, so we should escape '\'
                $NameWithDirTag = (Split-Path -Path $_.FullName -NoQualifier)  -replace [regex]::Escape('\'), '-'

                # Join new file name with destination directory
                $NewPath = Join-Path -Path $Dst -ChildPath $NameWithDirTag
            }
            # Don't modify new file path, if file doesn't exist in target dir
            else
            {
                $NewPath = $Dst
            }

            # Copy file
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $NewPath
        }
```

Ok this is what I have change and worked but is only working with one  record

```
$Src = '\\192.168.0.216\home\'
$Dst = Get-Content 'C:\TEST\path.txt'

# Wildcard for filter
$Extension = Get-Content 'C:\TEST\file.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you the problem, you can't use an array as the filter for `get-childitem`.  you can probably nest a `where-object` filter inside of a `foreach` loop but the easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to do is going to be to loop through your extension filters and then run your loop inside of that loop.  so wrap your entire `Get-ChildItem` loop in a `Foreach` loop as below.

```
Foreach($e in $extension){
  *Your Code Here*
}
```

Of cource make sure to change the `-Filter` parameter of your `Get-ChildItem` from `$Extension` to `$e`

Answer (score 0):

Like error says, `-Filter` expects a single string. `Get-Content` would be returning an object array for files with more than one line.

Since you are also using `-Recurse` consider using `-Include` instead of `-Filter` since it supports arrays of stings. This *should* without changing your input file or adding any other post processing. From [MSDN]

> Specifies, as a **string array**, an item or items that this cmdlet includes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt. Wildcards are permitted.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Include $Extension -Recurse
```

Note:

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

Same goes for `-Exclude` as well